# Why are the default string representations for for Intl and Reflect, `[object Object]`?

Tags: javascript

The string tags for built-in "namespace" objects like `Math` and `JSON` are eponymous.

But this is not the case for `Intl` and `Reflect`. Why?

```js
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(Math))    // [object Math]
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(JSON))    // [object JSON]
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(Atomics)) // [object Atomics]

// ...but

console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(Intl))    // [object Object] (?!)
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(Reflect)) // [object Object] (?!)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that's what the specification requires.

The ECMAScript Specification says that the `Math` object should have a `[Symbol.toStringTag]` value of `Math` [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-math-@@tostringtag). The same is true for [Atomics](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-atomics-@@tostringtag) and [JSON](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-json-@@tostringtag).

However, there is no such requirement for [the Intl object](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#intl-object), nor for the [Reflect](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-reflect-object) object. (Well, there *wasn't* such a requirement for Reflect, but that changed [in July 2020](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pull/2057))

For `Reflect` and `Intl`, [allenwb says that](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/495) the tag was not added because:

> Prior to ES5 the only namespace-like object in ES was the Math object. For reasons probably lost to history it was specified with a [[Class]] internal internal property whose value was "Math". In all other respects it was what we now call an ordinary object.
>
> ES5 added the JSON object as a namespace object and we just followed the pattern established by Math.
>
> ECMA-402 edition 1 **introduce the Intl object as a name space object. It was just an ordinary object and was not specified to have a [[Class]] internal property. So, it would O.p.toString as "[object Object]".**
>
> ES6 eliminated [[Class]] because it was being wide misused, in conjunction with Object.prototype.toString to perform (often unnecessary or undesirable) pseudo nominal type checking. Instead we made O.p.toString extensible via the @@toStringTag property. For backwards compatibility, we changed O.p.toString such that all the truly exotic objects from ES5 were detectable within toString such that their legacy toString value was maintained. That left Math and JSON (which in ES6 are just ordinary objects) as the only legacy ordinary objects that had special legacy O.p.toString behavior. We used the @@toStringTag mechanism to make their O.p.toString behavior backwards compatible.
>
> For new ES6 build-in "classes" (Promise, Map, Set, Float32Array, etc.) we provided a @@toStringTag method on their prototype objects such that the instances of those classes would be identified as such by O.p.toString.
>
> **Reflect isn't a "class", it is just namespace defined using an ordinary object.** Such name space objects are now widely used in JS code and typically don't have custom toString behavior. **So we followed the precedent of ECMA-402 Intl and did not give Reflect its own @@toStringTag**
>
> Part of the motivation, was a desire during ES6 that we should minimize the specialness of builtins. In general, we wanted built-ins to be as much as possible just ordinary objects that might be implemented by everyday JS programmers and hence the builtins should generally follow the same conventions as we expect ordinary JS programmers to follow. For the class-like buildins we established a new convention of using @@tostring on the prototype to name class instances. Hopefully that is a convention that will catch on with JS programmers. For namespace objects like Reflect we expect JS programmers to continue to use direct object instance (often constructed via object literals) and that they typically won't give them unique @@toStringTag properties. **So most name spaces including Intl and Reflect will print as "[object Object]".**

An issue was raised with TC39 about how adding `toStringTag`s to new namespaces would make sense and make things more consistent. As a result, Reflect now has such a tag, and browsers in late 2020 will start supporting it. Chrome supports it [starting in 86](https://v8.dev/blog/v8-release-86):

```js
console.log(Reflect[Symbol.toStringTag]);
```

Comment: Just an IMO, but I feel that the misuse and/or the intent to minimize specialness of builtins as a goal for ES6 should be highlighted.

Comment: This actually raises the question: why is `Atomics` different?

Comment: _"established a new convention of using @@tostring on the prototype to name class instances"_. Did AWB mean `@@toStringTag`? `toString` is overridden for a variety of purposes (mainly not to reveal the "name" of the class).

Comment: Just found out: `Atomics` does not follow the new convention due to those designers being unaware of the updated convention. https://twitter.com/awbjs/status/1259479922071842817?s=20

Comment: Also: there is an [active question](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/1970) about all this.